# RSA python3 - decryption output not equivalent to message

Tags: python, rsa

I have been trying to create a basic encryption/decryption code for an input message (which is a number). However my decryption code does not produce the message.  The e value was chosen to be 19 (its small bc its a proof of concept) and the two prime numbers that multiply to yield n are 41 and 29.  I was able to find d to be 59 through a mod inverse code I found online.  What could be going wrong?

```py
# encryption function
def encrypt(msg):
    encryption = (msg ** e) % n
    return encryption

# decryption function
def decrypt(encrypt):
    decryption = (encrypt ** d) % n
    return decryption
```

(btw n is the modulus, e is the part of the public key and d is the part of the private key)

Comment: Where are you getting `e`, `d` & `n` from?

Comment: please show how you are getting ```e```, ```d``` and ```n```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not much clear because i don't know from where and how you are getting the values of e,d and n. Try this basic implementation of RSA algorithm in Cryptography.

```
from decimal import Decimal 

def gcd(a,b): 
    if b==0: 
        return a 
    else: 
        return gcd(b,a%b) 
p = int(input('Enter the value of p = ')) 
q = int(input('Enter the value of q = ')) 
no = int(input('Enter the value of text = ')) 
n = p*q 
t = (p-1)*(q-1) 

for e in range(2,t): 
    if gcd(e,t)== 1: 
        break


for i in range(1,10): 
    x = 1 + i*t 
    if x % e == 0: 
        d = int(x/e) 
        break
ctt = Decimal(0) 
ctt =pow(no,e) 
ct = ctt % n 

dtt = Decimal(0) 
dtt = pow(ct,d) 
dt = dtt % n 

print('n = '+str(n)+' e = '+str(e)+' t = '+str(t)+' d = '+str(d)+' cipher text = '+str(ct)+' decrypted text = '+str(dt))
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Always Welcome, keep supporting :)

Comment: The Decimal type doesn't add anything useful and your method of calculating `d` will not always work because you only run i up to 10 regardless of the size of t. Instead of `int(x/e) ` just use `x//e`. And finally, instead of `ctt =pow(no,e) ct = ctt % n` just use `pow(no, e, n)`. It's much simpler and faster.

Comment: Sure i will try